# Instagram follow on button click

Tags: java, android, api, instagram

I'm currently trying to add a feature which allows users to follow an instagram account by clicking a button. I've seen other apps use that but I could not figure out how. As you can see in this post, following people by using the api is no longer availible. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/
Maybe some of you know how to do what I want.

Comment: they have deprecated required API

Comment: oh ok, how can I get that?

Comment: Maybe you have to purchase now.

Comment: I don't really think so tbh.

Comment: They have closed and not sure whether it will be available or not

Comment: Yes but I think there is an other way of doing what I want without using the Api.

Comment: You have to redirect.

Comment: There are apps that don't and they work.

Comment: They might be using APIs that are deprecated now!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a hack that is..

```
  Intent externalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("instraURL"));
  startActivity(externalIntent);
```

App will move user to external Browser and browser will move user on Instagram app..

> As it is not perfect solution but i am just sharing because it can help developers when they don't have SDK.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want. I don't want to redirect the user to a profile, the profile should get followed on a button click.